# Returning immutable list

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am making a class named `Question`. This class have answers so I want to be able to return the list of answers attached to it.

However, if the user makes a change to the answer I want the user to invoke the update-method so I could do additional validations etc. Right now if the user gets the list of answers he still can change the answer by saying `question.getAnswers().get(0).setDescription("BLAH BLAH").`

So I thought of returning a copy of each answer, and let the user change this and the he have to merge/update it back to the question. With this approach I can ensure that the answer is valid but the equals method of the answer is based on the `description` and `correct` field and not on the `id` field because I use JPA. If the user changes an answer with this approach the update method will not find the answer because the description field has changed and it is not equal anymore so it doesn't find it in the list.

Any advices?

```
public void updateAnswer(Answer answer) {
    int index = answers.indexOf(answer);
    answers.set(index, answer);
}

public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(answers);
}


@Test
public void shouldUpdateAnswerInQuestion() {
    // Get first answer, make an update on the description
    // and then update answer on question.
    Answer answerThatWillBeUpdated = question.getAnswers().get(0);
    String updatedAnswerDescription = "Hey, it is now updated!";
    answerThatWillBeUpdated.setDescription(updatedAnswerDescription);
    question.updateAnswer(answerThatWillBeUpdated);

    // After updating check that the answer in the list is equal
    // to the answer updated.
    Answer answerFromList = question.getAnswers().get(0);

    assertEquals(answerThatWillBeUpdated, answerFromList);
}
```

The answer class:

```
public class Answer {

    private long id;
    private String description;
    private Boolean correct;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Who is "the user"? What does he get exactly: a detached question with its answers, or an attached question with its answers? And is he supposed to modify an answer, or a questions and its list of answers? Why don't you have a service `updateAnswer(Answer a)` in your service layer?

Comment: Because the question is the aggregate root

Answer (score 1):

You should re-think your design of the app but since I'm not really sure what your domain constraints are overall, I can't suggest a slight re-design or anything of the sort.

A simple and straightforward answer is: program to the interface, not to the implementation.  If you want to enforce the calling of an update method after a setter has been modified, consider using the Decorator pattern.

- create an interface
- have your concrete class implement this interface (Answer)
- add a concrete class (pick a better name but AnswerDecorator)that implements the interface that accepts the concrete class in the constructor of the class mentioned in the point above

Then you just delegate all methods to the inner-instance and for the methods you want to call update, do something like this:

public void setField( int a ) {
   innerInstance.setField(a);
   update(...);
}

Comment: But I don't want the entity to be read-only. The user must be allowed to change, but since the question is the aggregate root all actions should be done through the public methods of that.

Comment: that's ok, did you solve it?  if so, how?  you should post your solution if so.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the id field for comparison in the update method? When you give the user a copy of your answer object, make sure your copy has the same id as the current answer object. So when the user changes the answer, your update validation code can still find out what answer has been changed based on the id field.

Comment: The reason why I provided JPA to the context of the question was because then people would understand that it is "bad".

Comment: But you aren't storing stuff in the database until it is validated, right? Isn't it possible to simply delete that row and replace it with the new one once validation is done?

Answer (score 0):

Generally I know 2 solutions.

1. Return deep copy of the list instead of the source list. In this case any changes done by user in the answer's description will not have any effect. 
   This solution is simple but very ineffective from performance and memory utilization perspective. It is also not user-friendly. Good API should throw exception when user tries to perform restricted action.
2. Other solution is to return list of unmodifirable objects, i.e. objects that throw exception when user tries to call their setters.

There are several possible implementations of this solution.

2.1. Modify setters of your model classes. All setters should be able to throw exception if object is created in read-only mode.

2.2. User wrapper (decorator) pattern.

2.2.1. Create interfaces for all value objects and implement wrapper for each class. For example AnswerWrapper will implement interface Answer, hold inside wrapped object of type Answer, delegate all methods except setters to appropriate methods of this object and throw exception from each setter.

2.2.2. Use dynamic proxy technique. You still need interface but you do not have to implement all setters for all classes. This solution is similar to aspects.

2.3. Use aspects. For example AspectJ.

Answer (score 0):

The client code has the list so it knows the list index, have it tell you which one to update:

```
public void updateAnswer(int index, Answer newAnswer) {
    answers.set(index, answer);
}

// ...

Answer answerThatWillBeUpdated = question.getAnswers().get(0);
String updatedAnswerDescription = "Hey, it is now updated!";
answerThatWillBeUpdated.setDescription(updatedAnswerDescription);
question.updateAnswer(0,answerThatWillBeUpdated);
```